# Javascript then promise not sequential with Parse queries in for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, asynchronous, parse-platform

I wrote a sequence of functions which include Parse queries:

```
var query1 = new Parse.Query(Events);
    query1.equalTo("id_organizer", $localStorage.username);
    query1.greaterThanOrEqualTo("date_start",currentTime) 
    query1.each(function(results){
            var object = results;
            eventname = object.get("event_name");
            datestart = object.get("date_start");
            location = object.get("location");
            id_event = object.get("id_event")
            eventimagefile = object.get("event_image");
            eventimageurl = eventimagefile.url();
            description = object.get("description");
            id_organizer = object.get("id_organizer");
            min_twitter_followers = object.get("min_twitter_followers");
            min_instagram_followers = object.get("min_instagram_followers");
            min_facebook_friends = object.get("min_facebook_friends");
            max_number_requests = object.get("max_number_requests");
            eventDetails.push({'name':eventname,'location':location, 'datestart':datestart, 'eventphoto':eventimageurl,'organizer':id_organizer, 'description':description, 'minTwitterFollowers':min_twitter_followers, 'minFacebookFriends':min_facebook_friends, 'minInstagramFollowers':min_instagram_followers,'maxNumberRequests':max_number_requests, 'id_event':id_event})      
    }).then(function(){ 

        alert("start")

        var Attendees = Parse.Object.extend("Attendees");
        eventDetails.forEach(function(e){
            var query2 = new Parse.Query(Attendees);
            query2.equalTo("event_id", e.id_event);    
            query2.count({
                success: function(number) {
                    e["n_requests_received"] =  number;
                    alert("received")
                }
            })  

            var query3 = new Parse.Query(Attendees);
            query3.equalTo("event_id", e.id_event);
            query3.equalTo("status", "confirmed")
            query3.count({
                success: function(number) {
                    e["n_requests_confirmed"] =  number;
                   // alert("confirmed")
                }
            })
        })

}).then(function(){
    alert("end")
    alert(JSON.stringify(eventDetails))
    $scope.events = eventDetails;
    $localStorage.events = eventDetails;
    });
})
```

unfortunately the alert "end" is printed right after "start" without waiting for the queries (query1,query2) inside the foreach loop to be executed. Do you know how I can make the for loop with the 2 queries executed before the next then?

Comment: that is correct, as your functions in each `then` do not return a promise, so , through the standard mechanism of  promises, results in an immediately resolved promise with a value of undefined - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises/845/promise-chaining#t=201607271444164888416)

Comment: Can you please tell me a solution I don't get how I should put the 'then'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.then(function(){ 
        alert("start")
        var Attendees = Parse.Object.extend("Attendees");

        return Promise.all(eventDetails.map(detail => {
            return Promise.all([new Promise((res, rej) => {
                var query2 = new Parse.Query(Attendees);
                query2.equalTo("event_id", detail .id_event);    
                query2.count({
                    success: function(number) {
                        detail["n_requests_received"] =  number;
                        alert("received")
                        res('Some value if required'); //These are needed or promise chain will hang
                    }
                });
            }),
            new Promise((res, rej) => {
                var query3 = new Parse.Query(Attendees);
                query3.equalTo("event_id", detail .id_event);
                query3.equalTo("status", "confirmed")
                query3.count({
                    success: function(number) {
                        detail["n_requests_confirmed"] =  number;
                       // alert("confirmed")
                       res('Some value if required'); //These are needed or promise chain will hang
                    }
                });
            })]);
        }));
})
```

Promise chains will wait for promises. That is if a `.then` anywhere in the chain receives an unresolved promise it will wait for that promise to resolve.

So what you could do is use `Promise.all` which expects an array of promises and will resolve when they do. So map over your array `eventDetails` creating a promise from each cell. Inside each cell use another `Promise.all` to create two new promises for both of your `Query` objects.

This way your `.then` will wait for your `eventDetails` array of promises to resolve. Then each cell in `eventDetails` will wait for your array of queries to resolve.

NOTE: The `new Promise()` where we are creating promises. It passes you two callbacks to resolve or reject the promise. This is how you wrap old callback style API's in a promise. However if you do not call either of them to resolve or reject then the whole promise chain could hang (depending on its design) waiting for that promise to resolve.

Hope that makes sense. This is pseudo code but you should get the idea.

---

Disclaimer i have not used `Parse.Query` i do not know what it is. However this method is how i would handle the above program flow of using an old callback style API, where you essentially have nested loops.

---

Extra Disclaimer: My example is using ES6 syntax. Not all browsers (IE) support that yet.

---

EDIT: The op asked for a version without using the ES6 arrow functions so here you are. There's lots of info on StackOverflow about arrow functions, that and Google. As you can see theres not much difference in terms of syntax. The power comes from how it binds the scope and also when your writing code in a more functional style.

```
.then(function(){ 
        alert("start")
        var Attendees = Parse.Object.extend("Attendees");

        return Promise.all(eventDetails.map(function (detail) {
            return Promise.all([new Promise(function (res, rej) {
                var query2 = new Parse.Query(Attendees);
                query2.equalTo("event_id", detail .id_event);    
                query2.count({
                    success: function(number) {
                        detail["n_requests_received"] =  number;
                        alert("received")
                        res('Some value if required'); //These are needed or promise chain will hang
                    }
                });
            }),
            new Promise(function (res, rej) {
                var query3 = new Parse.Query(Attendees);
                query3.equalTo("event_id", detail .id_event);
                query3.equalTo("status", "confirmed")
                query3.count({
                    success: function(number) {
                        detail["n_requests_confirmed"] =  number;
                       // alert("confirmed")
                       res('Some value if required'); //These are needed or promise chain will hang
                    }
                });
            })]);
        }));
})
```

Comment: thanks it works. For sake of completeness, 'e' should be details in your code.

Comment: just tested in ios since this is part of an ionic app. The promises do not work on ionic in ios

Comment: I will update 'e' when I'm back on by desktop, glad it helped. In terms of promises I assumed as your already had a '.then' method you were using promises already. If not you could pollyfill it. That's the issue with using the latest and greatest features. Not everyone supports them.

Comment: do you know how to do the code above with then instead of ES6 =>? It would help me a lot.

Comment: @ai20 Updated my answer.